# How can I change the content of HTML elements on native Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML code:

```
<a class="show_dropdown_make_call" href="/">380502543445</a>
<a class="show_dropdown_make_call" href="/">380502543890</a>
<a class="show_dropdown_make_call" href="/">380507893445</a>
<a class="show_dropdown_make_call" href="/">380563443445</a>
<a class="show_dropdown_make_call" href="/">380508763445</a>
```

**How to make “Call” instead of phone numbers?**

Tried it like this but nothing works.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('show_dropdown_make_call').innerHTML = 'To call';
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return one element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score -2):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.show_dropdown_make_call').forEach(
  x => x.innerText = 'Call'
)
```

```html
<a class="show_dropdown_make_call" href="/">380502543445</a>
<a class="show_dropdown_make_call" href="/">380502543890</a>
<a class="show_dropdown_make_call" href="/">380507893445</a>
<a class="show_dropdown_make_call" href="/">380563443445</a>
<a class="show_dropdown_make_call" href="/">380508763445</a>
```